# Why tycho-surefire-plugin:test considers Bundle-ClassPath instead of bin.includes?

Tags: eclipse, tycho, surefire, tycho-surefire-plugin

In my eclipse plugin project. I have a specific jar that I need it to be visible in the build process specially in test phase, However I don't need it to be visible in runtime of the eclipse plugin. I find that **tycho-surefire-plugin** is using the jars which existing in Bundle-ClassPath of the **MANIFEST.MF** instead of bin.includes of **build.properties**. Is there any way to force **tycho-surefire-plugin** to get its classpath from build.properties instead of MANIFEST.MF? as I see this is the normal difference between the two files.

My fragment test project pom is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>projectparent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../../../../projectparent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>com.myproject.projecttest</artifactId>
    <packaging>eclipse-test-plugin</packaging>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description>
        Tests for my project
    </description>

    <properties>
        <maven.site.skip>true</maven.site.skip>
        <maven.site.deploy.skip>true</maven.site.deploy.skip>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: how did you configured your test "target-platform" !!?? any pom?

Comment: @Hishamkh the test fragment has a very simple pom file. I didn't configure the "target-platform" in pom.

Comment: may you post the test pom in your question?

Comment: @Hishamkh I added the test pom in the question description.

Answer (score 1):

If I have correct understood your question:

- you have some dependencies, that you need to use them only during the testing phase but not including them in your product.

for doing this you have to use the target-platform-configuration plugin for the test and then specifying  `extraRequirements` to include your test only dependencies.

Example target-platform-configuration:

```
  <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <environments>
                    <environment>
                        <os>win32</os>
                        <ws>win32</ws>
                        <arch>x86</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <ws>gtk</ws>
                        <arch>x86</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <ws>gtk</ws>
                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                    </environment>
                </environments>
                <dependency-resolution>
                    <optionalDependencies>ignore</optionalDependencies>
                    <extraRequirements>
                        <requirement>
                            <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
                            <id>org.eclipse.ui</id>
                            <versionRange>0.0.0</versionRange>
                        </requirement>
                        <requirement>
                            <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
                             <id>org.eclipse.ui.views</id>
                            <versionRange>0.0.0</versionRange>
                        </requirement>
                        <requirement>
                            .....
                        </requirement>
                    </extraRequirements>
                </dependency-resolution>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

include this in your test pom.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But In my case the extra requirement is not an eclipse-plugin it is a normal jar. specifically, it is the javafx jar "jfxrt.jar". So is there any way to consider it as an extraRequirements?